# How to parse logs with nested json arrays in logstash using only grok and json filter?

Tags: arrays, json, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

**I am trying to parse the logs with nested json arrays. When I use json filter it goes well with first level parsing and anyhow parses the log but the nested array is not parsed and I get error in Kibana when I try to view it.**
 This is the log:

```
    {
        "a": "one",
        "b": "two",
        "c": {
            "alpha": "awesome"
        },
        "d": "three",
        "e": [
            {
                "f": "four",
                "g": "five,six,seven"
            },
            {}
        ],
        "close": ""
    }
```

The config I have used is :

```
    input     {   
        file     {
            codec => multiline
            {
                pattern => "^\]" 
                negate => true
                what => previous               
            }
        type => "log"
            tags => "name"
            path => ["/path/to/log" ]
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
    }
    filter {

      grok {

        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP:} %{GREEDYDATA:}" }

      }

    json {  source => "payload" }
    }

    output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "logstash-%{type}"
        host => "localhost"
        port => "9200"
        cluster => "elasticsearch"
      }
     stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
```

This config parses the logs however the nested json arrays are not handled and Kibana gives the error.

Comment: It might also be because your JSON is malformed, see the last element in your array has a comma appended, which is not valid. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited json, check now.

Comment: Well, do you still see the error after correcting this issue?

Comment: yes, still facing the same issue.

Comment: Ok, could you update your question with a few lines from a real file that you're trying to process?